# Drupal field with mp3 files in - play as playlist with titles

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I have a custom 'Player' node type in Drupal with a CCK file field allowing multiple mp3 files to be uploaded (3 in this instance). Currently I have [SWFTools](http://drupal.org/project/swftools) installed and most of the players that supports. So far I have been using [FlowPlayer3](http://www.flowplayer.org/) for it, which does everything I want except display the track names. I've tried most of the other players and they don't seem to do it either.

I do have the [getID3](http://drupal.org/project/getID3) module & associated files installed before anyone asks...

Any idea how I can get all these things to work together?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I just used the MP3 player module and got each one to display separately instead of as a playlist... not really what I wanted, but it was the best I could do...

Answer (score 2):

You can try jPlayer, it can play list of audio
http://www.jplayer.org/ ( Download and put it inside libraries folder)

This is jplayer module for drupal
http://drupal.org/project/jplayer